# SqlMetal (v7.1) still bombs when getting a sproc with a table-valued param in SqlServer 2008 instead of Skipping and Continuing

Tags: sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql, sqlmetal

According to this post: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/362523/sqlmetal-error-when-used-on-a-database-with-a-table-valued-parameter#tabs

and several other posts I've found containing a list of features and bug fixes for LINQ to Sql in 4.0 this was supposed to be fixed in that it would simply ignore that Sproc and go on it's merry way.

> SQL Metal
>
> > 1. Foreign key property setter now checks all affected associations not just the first
> > 2. Improved error handling when primary key type not supported
> > 3. ***Now skips stored procedures containing table-valued parameters instead of aborting process***
> > 4. Can now be used against connections that use AttachDbFilename syntax
> > 5. No longer crashes when unexpected data types are encountered

I have installed the newest SDK (v7.1) and sqlmetal.exe is still not getting past that stored procedure.

Does anyone know if that promised improvement (of skipping instead of bombing) was included?  And if so, in which version?